# `Template` in a OOP form

Tags: python, string, oop, types

I want to use string.Template in a OOP way but i'm getting an error

```
from string import Template

class Foo:
   def __init__(self):
       self.template()
       self.bar = type

   def template(self):
       self.bar = Template('$who')

   def get_result(self):
       print(self.bar.substitute(who="Me"))

some = Foo()
some.get_result()
```

But I am getting an error stating
`AttributeError: type object 'type' has no attribute 'substitute'`
.
And if change the data type of `self.bar` to `None` it gives
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'substitute'`.

Comment: What is the `self.bar = type` line for? You're reassigning that variable to a much less useful value.

Comment: thank you , I got it how to solve the error , but is there a more efficent way of writing this code ? @SilvioMayolo

Comment: I'm afraid your code snippet may be too oversimplified for me to be able to answer that well. Your code can be made way more efficient by shortening the whole thing to `print("Me")`, but obviously that's not what you mean. It's going to depend on what you're actually doing with this code. `Template` is overkill for lots of things (`f""` strings are simpler and more readable, and honestly I have never personally used the `Template` class directly myself).